# How to convert &#8211,&#8222 etc in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I made server side by Python and which return some scraped html string to client side which is made by Objective-C.

But When I try to show from client side which retuned string from server , it contains &#8211,&#8222,etc.But I don't know why it contains above characters.

Do you have any idea? And I want to convert them correctly with Objective-C. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are decimal codes, and they are language-agnostic.  I think you mean you want them in UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with Cocoa you could also try to use NSAttributedString and `initWithHTML:documentAttributes:`, you will lose the markup than, though:

```
NSData *data = [@"<html><p>&#8211 Test</p></html>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data documentAttributes:nil];
NSString *result = [string string];
```

Comment: Should be there:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

These are [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)
Here is [NSString category for HTML](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m) and here are the methods available:

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```